# Scaling images down looks awful

Tags: image, actionscript-3, scaling

I have an image for a mobile game and im scaling it down depending on the screen but the image looks awful, for example some lines dissapear, its like the image squeezes and the lines are so thin they simply dissapear. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In As3 Bitmaps have property `smoothing`, and by default It's `false`.
Set it to `true`, and you will have better results.

Comment: Im not loading them yet im just trying them by dragging it into a symbol from the library and smoothing is turned on in the image file's properties

Comment: I see. Do you do proportional scaling? Also there is bitmap artefacts, if you do big scaling, like from 1600px to the 200px. Also try to get closest images size for your needs. If you need image by design near 400x400, don't store in the library image 1400x1400